# Does Azure Bastion with AAD Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I recently created a Azure Bastion service and Azure VM in my organisation's Subscription. When I try to connect to the VM via the Bastion using local Admin ID it worked. However the same is failing when I try with my Azure AD ID. Is this a limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (2) authentication schemes:

- Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication: Azure Bastion does **not** currently support authentication using AAD-based (cloud) users. This request is known and prioritized as "high" by the product team. See this [link][1] for details in user voice. The advantage of this approach is to provide full cloud-based authentication, with no dependency on on-premises technology (in this case, Active Directory). One workaround for now is to expose a jumpoint on a vNet until availability of this feature.
- Azure Directory (AD) authentication: Azure Bastion does currently support authentication using AD-based users (Windows AD User). Since this is a managed "Active Directory" provided by Microsoft, the use of Azure AD Connect is needed to sync this domain (and users) to Azure Active Directory (AAD). The drawback of this approach is to continue building using on-premises technology (Active Directory).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. However, if I have domain joined VM using Azure AD DS would it still be considered as a AAD authentication or would it be possible to login via Bastion or can we login only via local accounts?

Comment: I just added more information. Short answer: it will work but, you continue to build around legacy technologies since AD DS is just a Active Domain managed service provided by Microsoft. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does Bastion support Linux VMs using the AADSSHLoginForLinux VM extension?

Answer (score 0):

Public preview announced during Microsoft Ignite 2021 to include support for Azure AD login for Bastion enabled VMs. It is available using Azure CLI client on Windows and leveraging native client (openSSH to do Azure AD based SSH for Linux and mstsc to do Azure AD based RDP for Windows). Details can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-native-client-windows